# can't get ArangoDB2.2 working

Tags: arangodb

I installed ArangoDB2.2 as a service (and uninstalled 2.1.2), but can't get it working. After re-starting Windows7, I could not get the Web Interface page to load in Firefox. I tried to start ArangoDB via arangosh, but could not get any positive response. I got various error messages about syntax, like Program Files is not recognized. It may be my error, but Program Files is in the path.

I uninstalled 2.2, and re-installed Arango2.1.2 as a service. Everything works fine.  It starts with the Windows Restart, and the Web Interface at port 8529 works.

Does Arango2.2 have bugs related to starting as a service in Windows and recognizing the port 8529 Web page?  If not, can someone describe clearly how to get these working in Arango2.2? I'm real new at this, but I'd like to use the latest version.

Comment: I've tried ArangoDB 2.2.0 64bit under Windows 7: no problem there. Can you check the "Services" system dialog. Is there a ArangoDB? What is the status?

Comment: I uninstalled 2.1.2, and re-installed 2.2.  This time it works. Thanks for providing a bit of confidence. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a summary of the comments above. Steps are

- uninstall the old version
- download the new version from the web-site https://www.arangodb.org/download
- install the new version
- open the service dialog and check that ArangoDB has been started